# ubuntu 18.10 screen flickering solved

Tags: nvidia, screen, samsung, 18.10, flicker

[example of the screen flickering in YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZvH5ef5ruI)

I upgraded to ubuntu 18.10 a couple of days ago and noticed that my screen flickered with some YT videos. I changed to the proprietary nvidia drivers (1060 series) and that didn't solve the problem.

I have a dual screen setup (my TV) and the YT videos played normally on my TV but not on the monitor, besides YT I have problems with some webs
e.g. https://www.smashwords.com/shelves/category/1 but if I scroll down a couple of lines the monitor works again.

There seems to be some config problem with my monitor, it worked ok before the upgrade (W10 and ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I went to NVIDIA X Server settings and selected the screen with the problem. On the "controls" tab I changed the "Color Space" from "RGB" to "YCbCr444" and it stopped the problems.